# How best to determine how far through the DOM an element/node is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to find out how far through a document a specific element is, ideally as a percentage.

Specifically, I have a long XHTML document (it's a component of an ePub file, in fact), and I've got one `<span id="where_am_i">hello</span>` somewhere within it.

If this was the very first element in the document, the "percentage through" value would be 0. If it was exactly half-way through the document, it would be 50.

It won't necessarily be the top layer, it may be nested within other nodes.

I've considered using something like a recursive `$(node).contents().each(function(){...});` and counting words to get to it, though I wonder if that might be a slow way to do it?

The document is text, it's very unlikely to contain images, or massively differing text size, so it's fine to just find out how far through the text `#where_am_i` is.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how far, as in its pixel location? be very specific.

Comment: By half-way, you mean its position in the document or its position in the dom tree?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, both of you. I mean textually, how far through the whole document it would be. I'm not sure what the difference is between "position in the document" and "position in the dom tree" – wouldn't these both return the same % value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this treeWalk function to find out where in the document a given element is:

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LGT6x/

```
function findElementPercentage(target) {
    var cnt = 0;
    var pos;
    treeWalkFast(document.body, function(node) {
        if (node === target) {
            pos = cnt;
        }
        ++cnt;
    });
    // handle situation where target was not found
    if (pos === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    // return percentage
    return (pos / cnt) * 100;
}

var treeWalkFast = (function() {
    // create closure for constants
    var skipTags = {"SCRIPT": true, "IFRAME": true, "OBJECT": true, 
        "EMBED": true, "STYLE": true, "LINK": true, "META": true};
    return function(parent, fn, allNodes) {
        var node = parent.firstChild, nextNode;
        while (node && node != parent) {
            if (allNodes || node.nodeType === 1) {
                if (fn(node) === false) {
                    return(false);
                }
            }
            // if it's an element &&
            //    has children &&
            //    has a tagname && is not in the skipTags list
            //  then, we can enumerate children
            if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.firstChild && !(node.tagName && skipTags[node.tagName])) {
                node = node.firstChild;
            } else  if (node.nextSibling) {
                node = node.nextSibling;
            } else {
                // no child and no nextsibling
                // find parent that has a nextSibling
                while ((node = node.parentNode) != parent) {
                    if (node.nextSibling) {
                        node = node.nextSibling;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

---

FYI, you could probably also just use `document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")` and then walk through the nodeList until you find your element and use that index as a measure of how far you are through the whole list.

```
function findElementPercentage(target) {
    var all = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        if (all[i] === target) {
            return (i/all.length) * 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/AUjq7/

Comment: Thanks, @jfriend00 I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes!

Comment: @JoLoCo - added another fairly simple method to the end of my answer.

Comment: I selected your answer as it was the most accurate. Though it could be slow, it did exactly as I needed it to. I was able to amend it to be even more accurate by counting the length of the text in each node and comparing it against the length of the text of the entire document. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you have your document as a string, you can get a *very* rough estimate by using the [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) javascript function

```
var html = $('body').html(); // or provided string
var percentage = html.indexOf('where_am_i') / html.length; 
var found = percentage >= 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Aurélien, that's an interesting solution – rough, but no doubt fast! I'll give it a try and let you know my results.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery solution:

```
<div>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>

var all=$("*").not("script, IFRAME, STYLE, EMBED, OBJECT, head, html,body, meta, title, link");
function getPercentage(el){
    return all.index($(el))/all.length*100;
}
console.log(getPercentage("#test"))//25
```