# "False" text node causing trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, traversal

I'm working on a DOM traversal type of script and I'm almost finished with it. However, there is one problem that I've encountered and for the life of me, I can't figure out what to do to fix it. Pardon my ineptitude, as I'm brand new to JS/JQuery and I'm still learning the ropes.

Basically, I'm using Javascript/JQuery to create an "outline", representing the structure of an HTML page, and appending the "outline" to the bottom of the webpage. For example, if the HTML is this...

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <script src=”http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js” type=”text/javascript”>
        </script>
        <script src=”outline.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then the output should be an unordered list like this:

- html

  - head
  - body

    - h1

      - text(Hello World)
    - script src(”http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js”) type(”text/javascript”)
    - script src(”outline.js”) type(”text/javascript”)

Here's what I've got so far:

```
var items=[];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("<ul id = 'list'></ul>").appendTo("body");

    traverse(document, function (node) { 
        if(node.nodeName.indexOf("#") <= -1){
            items.push("<ul>"+"<li>"+node.nodeName.toLowerCase());
        }
        else {
            var x = "text("+node.nodeValue+")";
            if(node.nodeValue == null) {
                items.push("<li> document");
            }
            else if(/[a-z0-9]/i.test(node.nodeValue) && node.nodeValue != null) {
                items.push("<ul><li>"+ x +"</ul>");
            }
            else {
                items.push("</ul>");
            }
        }
    });
    $('#list').append(items.join(''));
});

function traverse(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        traverse(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

It works almost perfectly, except it seems to read a carriage return as a text node. For example, if there's

```
<head><title>
```

it reads that properly, adding head as an unordered list element, and then creating a new "unordered list" for title, which is nested inside the header. HOWEVER, if it's

```
<head>
    <title>
```

It makes the new unordered list and its element, "head", but then jumps to the else statement that does `items.push(</ul>)` . How do I get it to ignore the carriage return? I tried testing to see if the nodeValue was equal to the carriage return, \r, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: in the second form, there is a #text node before the title node

Comment: Are you just trying to ignore text nodes entirely so you just capture the named tags?  If so, you can just skip any nodes with `node.nodeType === 3` or alternatively only pay attention to `node.nodeType === 1` element tags.  FYI, here's a pre-built `treeWalk()` function that lets you optionally skip text nodes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329665/how-best-to-determine-how-far-through-the-dom-an-element-node-is/23329876#23329876 and it also avoids walking into things like `<script>` tags or `<iframe>` tags.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your help! I'm not trying to ignore all text nodes--I want to preserve the text nodes in, say, <p> tags or header tags, but I want to ignore all other extraneous ones, like the ones caused by carriage returns. I'm sure I'm not handling this in the most efficient way possible, but now that I'm in so deep, I'm determined to make it work somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding exactly which text nodes you want to skip.  If you just want to skip a text node that is only whitespace, you can do that like this:

```
var onlyWhitespaceRegex = /^\s*$/;

traverse(document, function (node) { 
    if (node.nodeType === 3 && onlyWhitespaceRegex.test(node.nodeValue) {
        // skip text nodes that contain only whitespace
        return;
    }
    else if (node.nodeName.indexOf("#") <= -1){
        items.push("<ul>"+"<li>"+node.nodeName.toLowerCase());
    } else ...
```

Or, maybe you just want to trim any multiple leading or trailing whitespaces off a text node before displaying it since it may not display in HTML.

```
var trimWhitespaceRegex = /^\s+|\s+$/g;

traverse(document, function (node) { 
    if(node.nodeName.indexOf("#") <= -1){
        items.push("<ul>"+"<li>"+node.nodeName.toLowerCase());
    } else {
        var text = node.nodeValue;
        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            text = text.replace(trimWhitespaceRegex, " ");
        }
        var x = "text("+text+")";
        if(node.nodeValue == null) {
            items.push("<li> document");
        } ....
```

A further description of exactly what you're trying to achieve in the output for various forms of different text nodes would help us better understand your requirements.

Comment: Basically, my javascript reads all carriage returns/new lines AND all HTML end tags as text nodes with nodeValues of whitespace. I'm having trouble differentiating between the two of them. I need to know which text nodes are HTML end tags because my plan was that I would end the most nested unordered list when I came upon a text node that represented an HTML end tag. How can I tell the difference between those two and skip past all the text nodes that represent returns/new lines? I tried doing a regex that checks for \r, but it didn't work, oddly.

Comment: @clf08527 - I don't know why there would be any confusion between a text node and an HTML tag.  The `nodeType === 3`on a text node and `nodeType === 1` on an element, so you should be able to very easily tell what is a text node and what is some other kind of node by checking that.  You will notice that your code never looks at `.nodeType` (that's a problem) and both of my examples do look at `.nodeType`.  You need to be paying attention to that.  See [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) for a listing of `nodeType` values.

Comment: @clf08527 - As you presumably know, HTML ignores all carriage returns except for a few circumstances such as inside a `<pre>` so you should probably be ignoring carriage returns in the text (convert them to a single whitespace character because that's how they usually behave).  Again, I don't really understand what your specific problem is with carriage returns.

Comment: @clf08527 - Did you get a solution to your issue?  If so, please mark this (or some other answer) as your selected answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and this will indicate to the community that your question has been answered and will earn you some reputation points that can earn you more privileges over time here.